# Deprotection (debenzoylation) of glucose (sacharide) using NaOMe leads to hydrolysis glucose

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I have a problem removing the benzoyl groups of my glucose moiety using sodium methylate (standard procedure). Indeed, the benzoyl groups are removed. However, a significant amount of glucose gets hydrolysed leaving an alcohol group. I have tried different equivalents of sodium methylate and also other bases like potassium carbonate and ammonia. However, in all cases hydrolysis takes place.

[image: Reactions]

Does anyone have an idea why hydrolysis takes place? Could it have something to do with the TMSOTf (strong acid) in the previous step? The only workup I did for compound **1** was quenching the reaction using the same molar amount of TEA as TMSOTf, then evaporating $\ce{CHCl3}$, then silica column chromatography ($\ce{CHCl3 : MeOH}$ in $10 : 1$, see picture). Is it possible that TMSOTf is still present in my compound?

Column of compound **1**:
[image: Column after TMSOTf reaction:]

Comment: The mildest conditions I know of for ester hydrolysis is LiOH in 19/1 THF/water at room temp. Could be worth trying.

Comment: I very much doubt TMSOTf would survive the presence of the MeOH in your eluent

Comment: What's the water content of the methanol?

Comment: How do you know that the first step was complete. Was the benzoylglucoside pure?

Comment: MeOH is of AR quality.

Comment: The benzoylglucoside was pure as shown by MALDI and NMR.

Comment: Et3NTMS+ OTf- may still be a silylating agent that removes your fatty alohol in the CHCl3 evaporation (moist) or on silica gel.